# Using CGDisplayStreamCreate with Metal

Tags: macos, metal, screen-capture

I am trying to use CGDisplayStreamCreate to capture the display and use the textures in a metal shader.

The code works all the way to getting the samples back from CGDisplayStreamCreate, but I cannot find a way to use those samples in a Metal shader.

Once I receive the sample from the CGDisplayStreamCreate callback, I create a CVPixelBuffer with CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes() and then call CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage() to get a metal texture out of it.

The call to CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage fails with -6660.

It seems that the IOSurface created by the CGDisplayStream api is not compatible with metal but with openGL only.

I have tried to pass kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey attributes to the different function calls to no avail.

Is there a way to use metal with buffers from CGDisplayStreamCreate?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the issue.
I was creating the pixel buffer using `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes()` with the result of `IOSurfaceGetBaseAddress()` and that doesn't work.
The solution is to create the pixel buffer using `CVPixelBufferCreateWithIOSurface`!